# Excel how copy row of data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 if a cell <= Value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to put together an Excel sheet that will help track when services are due for certain vehicles.

The idea is that the sheet will automatically track how many days until a service is needed. I have conditional formatting on the countdown column that if it displays a number less than or equal to 5 it turns red. 
I would like to take this a step further so that any vehicle displaying 5 or less days gets copied to sheet 2.

[image]

So if the countdown column displays 5 or less days I would like it to copy some of the columns in the row to Sheet 2 and continue function (the countdown still ticks down).

If that isn't possible the entire row would be fine also.

[image]

This way any vehicle that needs a service is displayed in the same area.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [Copy Filtered Row by Color to new sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437131/copy-filtered-row-by-color-to-new-sheet/29442727#29442727).

Comment: Would it not be easier to use a pivot table and filter on countdown?

Comment: I'd advise you to work with an event which is launched when your worksheet is changed: you can find this in VBA editor: VBAProject, Microsoft Excel Objects, Sheet_x, Worksheet, Change. The target in the parameter list of the "Change" event equals the data which are changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not VBA expert but you can try this for starter.

Paste this code in Alt+F11 -> VBAProject -> Microsoft Excel Objects -> Sheet1 (Sheet1)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Declarations
Dim c1 As Object
Dim c2 As Object
Dim countdown As Integer
Dim rego As String
Dim duedt As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:C500").Clear
'Copy row
For Each c1 In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E3:E500").Cells
    If c1.Value <= 5 And c1.Value <> 0 Then
        countdown = c1.Value
        rego = c1.Offset(0, -4).Value
        duedt = c1.Offset(0, -1).Value
        For Each c2 In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C500").Cells
            If c2.Value = "" Then
                c2.Value = countdown
                c2.Offset(0, -2).Value = rego
                c2.Offset(0, -1).Value = duedt
            Exit For
            End If
        Next c2
    End If
    If c1.Value = 0 Then
    Exit For
    End If
Next c1

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I am assuming 'Countdown' won't have '0' value and you will have maximum 500 entries.

Comment: If you want '0' value to allow in countdown cells, just replace "c1.Value <> 0" by "Not IsEmpty(c1)" and "c1.Value = 0" by "IsEmpty(c1)".

Comment: Thanks, this works great. It's everything I hoped for :D

Comment: Say I wanted to pull the data from multiple sheets. Like sorting the vehicles by manufacturer. 
Like Sheet 1 would be Ford, Sheet 2 Toyota with sheet 3 being the Service Due sheet. 

Would this code still work?