# Copy paste the cells based on color(Red) into another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet of values as listed below where i have applied the conditional formatting to the cells based on target values to change the cell color.

```
If cells <= 10% to target = GREEN
   cells >10% & <25% to target = YELLOW
   cells >=25% to target = RED
```

See the below table for above conditions for colors

```
 PN      Target  Jan    Feb    Mar   
Mango      35    15     65     70    
Apple      50    54     56     15   
Grapes    20%    25%    55%    65%   
Banana    35%    90%    15%    65%
```

So based on all above conditions all the cells will have different colors. So, i want to only copy/pull cells that are RED and paste it into another sheet with same formatting using a VBA automatically every month to show case the utilization.

For example: Out of above example say the below cells are highlighted RED based on their utilization,

```
 PN      Target  Jan    Feb   Mar   
Mango      35           65    70    
Apple      50    54     56       
Grapes    20%           55%   65%   
Banana    35%    90%          65%
```

I only want to copy these above cells with data to another sheet automatically using a vba where it can recognize the cells highlighted as RED and select all with Product & headers name and paste into another sheet.

I would appreciate, if anyone can help in this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you filter by color to isolate then copy and paste the visible cells?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437131/copy-filtered-row-by-color-to-new-sheet/29442727#29442727

Comment: If you're using conditional formatting, you could use the original condition logic (i.e. >= 25% to target), or take a conditional formatting approach similar to what is laid out [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CFColors.htm).

Comment: You can also check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330345/vba-to-identify-cells-in-red.

Comment: Please, if possible provide the code to only copy red cells out of one sheet to another, if found any using Vba. I couldn't able to understand the attached examples and even they are completely different from my requirement

Comment: Is there any formula which i can use to check, if out of the selected range which cells are red(in which i have applied conditional formatting), so i can select on those cells and their product name to display only that cells in another sheet